# Como acceder a una posición de un array que está dentro de un atributo de una clase en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, frontend

estoy haciendo un ejercicio que consiste en crear una clase Disco y almacenar el nombre, grupo de música, año de publicación, el tipo de música que puede ser "rock", "pop", "punk" o "indie. El tipo de música lo he almacenado en un array, pero el problema es cuando yo instancio un objeto de la clase Disco y le asigno los valores en el constructor, no se como seleccionar un elemento de los que he almacenado dentro del array, porque si yo introduzco otro tipo de música que no tenga incluido dentro del array, me lo ejecuta igualmente. ¿Cómo podría hacer para acceder a uno de los elementos que incluí en el atributo que declaré como array?. Os enseño mi código.

```
class Disco{ //creo una clase Disco

    //atributos
    nombre;
    grupoMusica;
    anioPublicacion;
    tipoMusica = ["rock","pop","punk","indie"];
    localizacion;
    prestado = false;

    constructor(nombre,grupoMusica,anioPublicacion,tipoMusica,localizacion){ //constructor con parámetros
        //compruebo que no esten vacias las propiedades
        if(nombre != "" && grupoMusica != "" && anioPublicacion != "" && tipoMusica != [] && localizacion != undefined){ 
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.grupoMusica = grupoMusica;
            this.anioPublicacion = anioPublicacion;
            this.tipoMusica = tipoMusica;
            this.localizacion = localizacion;
            this.prestado = false;
        }else{
            this.nombre = "";
            this.grupoMusica = "";
            this.anioPublicacion = "";
            this.tipoMusica = [];
            this.localizacion = 0;
            this.prestado = false;
        }
    }

    cambiaNumEstanteria(num){ //metodo que cambia el numbero de estanteria de la localizacion
        this.localizacion = num;
    }

    cambiaPrestado(prop){ //metodo que cambia la propiedad de prestado
        this.prestado = prop;
    }

    toString(){ //muestro toda la información del disco

        return `El disco ${this.nombre} del grupo ${this.grupoMusica} del año ${this.anioPublicacion} del tipo ${this.tipoMusica}, está localizado en la estanteria ${this.localizacion}, su estado prestado es: ${this.prestado} `;

    }
}
```

Y este es el objeto que he instanciado para comprobar que me funcione bien.

```
disco2 = new Disco("Crazy World","The Scorpions","6 de noviembre de 1990","rap",3);
```

Como veis, en el tipoMusica he dado un valor que no está dentro del array y cuando yo lo ejecuto me sale esto como resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pero, en ningún momento en el código validas que el valor ingresado tenga que ser una de las opciones del array. Como esperas que se valide solo?

Tienes que hacer la validación tu mismo, algo asi:

```js
class Disco { //creo una clase Disco

  //atributos
  nombre;
  grupoMusica;
  anioPublicacion;
  tipoMusica;
  localizacion;
  prestado = false;
  tipoMusicaPermitido = ["rock", "pop", "punk", "indie"];

  validarTipoMusica(tipoMusica) {
     return this.tipoMusicaPermitido.includes(tipoMusica);
  }
  constructor(nombre, grupoMusica, anioPublicacion, tipoMusica, localizacion) { //constructor con parámetros
    //compruebo que no esten vacias las propiedades
    if (nombre != "" && grupoMusica != "" && anioPublicacion != "" && tipoMusica != [] && localizacion != undefined) {

      if(!this.validarTipoMusica(tipoMusica)){
         throw "Se intentó crear un disco con un tipo de musica invalido"
      }
      
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.grupoMusica = grupoMusica;
      this.anioPublicacion = anioPublicacion;
      this.tipoMusica = tipoMusica;
      this.localizacion = localizacion;
      this.prestado = false;
    } else {
      this.nombre = "";
      this.grupoMusica = "";
      this.anioPublicacion = "";
      this.tipoMusica = [];
      this.localizacion = 0;
      this.prestado = false;
    }
  }

  cambiaNumEstanteria(num) { //metodo que cambia el numbero de estanteria de la localizacion
    this.localizacion = num;
  }

  cambiaPrestado(prop) { //metodo que cambia la propiedad de prestado
    this.prestado = prop;
  }
  
  

  toString() { //muestro toda la información del disco

    return `El disco ${this.nombre} del grupo ${this.grupoMusica} del año ${this.anioPublicacion} del tipo ${this.tipoMusica}, está localizado en la estanteria ${this.localizacion}, su estado prestado es: ${this.prestado} `;

  }
}

disco1 = new Disco("Crazy World", "The Scorpions", "6 de noviembre de 1990", "pop", 3);
console.log(disco1.toString()); //funciona

disco2 = new Disco("Crazy World", "The Scorpions", "6 de noviembre de 1990", "rap", 3);
console.log(disco1.toString()); //lanza error
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ahora si que me funciona, no sabía que tenía que validar primero el tipo de música, ya que en clase no me dijeron nada de eso.